# Emails popping up back in Inbox after moving them or deleting them

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 and this problem popped up just a couple of days ago.
When I go and delete emails or move some others to my folders,the next time I go to look at my email, all the emails are back in my inbox as unread.
Whatever I had moved to the folders are back in my inbox and not in my folders.    This has happened everytime since it began a couple of days ago.
My OS is Windows  7 Home

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any rules configured in Outlook?

Are you sure all e-mail messages have been downloaded from the server?  Possibly a message with a  large attachment remaining?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a blackberry it is possible for that to be causing the issue. There are various articles about this basically saying ensure your conflict resolution is set to 'Server wins'